# Use of 'Snacks" in a sentence

Tags: grammatical-number

Is this correct?

Snacks is on me!

confused on the whether "snacks" should be in singular or plural form.

Comment: Generally it's treated as a "normal" noun -- "snack" is singular, "snacks" is plural.

Comment: so, is it safe to say, "snacks are on me!" ??

Answer (score 1):

If you and your friends plan to buy presents and foods for a surprise party, and you want to announce your willingness to pay for one of the snacks, or if you wake up only to find out someone put a snack on you while you were sleeping:

> A snack is on me!

If you want to say that you're going to take care of a special snack — that you're willing to pay for, or make for somebody:

> The snack is on me.

If want to say you're going to pay for the snacks:

> Snacks are on me!

Answer (score 0):

"Snack" is a countable noun and, therefore - provided your sentence means "I am volunteering to pay for the snacks" - it should be "Snacks are on me!"

"Snacks is on me!" sounds like somebody named Snacks just jumped on you.

Comment: What if _Snacks_ is a very hungry pet - like a dog or like the cookie monster?